# Overflow-y not working with fr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the next html structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <header></header>
  <div id="content">
     <div class="something"></div>
     <div class="lateralInfo">
        <div class="menu"></div>
        <div class="data">
             // A lot of data 
        </div>          
     </div>      
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

And using the next css  style:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

 #container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 10px;
    align-items:stretch;
    justify-items:stretch;
}
#content{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
    background-color:rgb(128, 126, 126);
}
.something{
    position: relative;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding:10px;
    margin:30px 0px;
} 
.lateralInfo{
    background-color:#eaeaea;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    align-content:flex-start;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
  .data{
     padding:10px;
     display:grid;
     grid-gap:10px;
     align-content: flex-start;
     overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This give me the next output: 
[image]

**The problem** comes when I insert a lot of `divs` in `.data`, where I writed `HERE` in the image.

```
.data{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

`overflow-y` is not working.
 I checked some post where they say that it needs `height` specified at the parent to work `but`:

Im using `fr` in all the parents of `.data` what means that they need to use al the free space, but not more. So the height is specified. Then why is not working?

---

Actually im using:

```
var contentHeight = $("#content").innerHeight();
$(".lateralInfo").css("height", contentHeight);
```

to set a height when the site loads to adjust to each screen,**But** this is what `fr` should be doing in css.

> So why is this happening since there is a fr height on all parents? And how to solve this with only css??

**JSFiddle** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1zkj3gr4/13/)

Comment: can you fork that up in a jsfiddle please?

Comment: @Viira added it for you

Comment: Where's the fiddle link?

Comment: @Dumisani edit needs to get accepted first. Or else the author has to add a fiddle

Comment: Done, sorry for being late but, there is some info that I can't made public and the file is pretty big to just make a copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS solution by Takit Isy will also scroll the `div class="menu"`.

I think when you want to solve that problem, you have to change the html code a little bit.

Starting from your original code, wrap a new `div style="position:relative"` around your `div class="data"` and add this to the CSS of `.data`:

```
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
```

**Explanation:**

Because of `fr` the last child node of `lateralInfo` will get some sort of min-height. But it won't get a max-height and you can't assign that manually, because it would be a formular.
That's why your old solution not worked.

So two problems had to be solved: don't let the last child element of `lateralInfo` grow to big and give the scrollable element some sort of max-height.
Wraping the new div around `div class="data"` and give `div class="data"` `position:absolute` solves the first problem (because the new div won't grow with it's absolute positioned content).
The second problem is solved by the `height:100%` (this works because we have the new parent element with the desired height).

**Full Code:**

```
<div id="container">
  <header></header>
  <div id="content">
     <div class="something"></div>
     <div class="lateralInfo">
        <div class="menu">menu doesn't scroll away</div>
        <div style="position:relative">
           <div class="data">
              // A lot of data 
           </div>          
        </div>
     </div>      
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

 #container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 10px;
    align-items:stretch;
    justify-items:stretch;
}
#content{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
    background-color:rgb(128, 126, 126);
}
.something{
    position: relative;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding:10px;
    margin:30px 0px;
} 
.lateralInfo{
    background-color:#eaeaea;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    align-content:flex-start;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
.data{
     position:absolute;
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     padding:10px;
     display:grid;
     grid-gap:10px;
     align-content: flex-start;
     overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank. Is exactly what I was looking for, but I swill see it a bit strange, As Takit Isy said, it needs a fiex height to work and `fr` dont' do that. Looking that this solution works,Is it posible that by this way it have a fixed height?

Comment: I changed the answer and added an explanation. I hope that answers your question. The scollable element has some sort of "fix" height because of the `height: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

You are using `1fr`, and that can't work with `overflow`.

> In order for overflow to have an effect, the block-level container
>   must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space
>   set to nowrap.

Documentation about `overflow`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

The `fr` unit is a fractional, flexible unit that distributes the available space. It doesn't define an actual `height`.

---

**Solutions**

1. Use JavaScript

Your JavaScript solution is a good way to correct that “unwanted” behaviour:

```js
$(".lateralInfo").css("height", $("#content").innerHeight());
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 10px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-items: stretch;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  background-color: rgb(128, 126, 126);
}

.something {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.lateralInfo {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.data {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  align-content: flex-start;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.server {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <header></header>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="something"></div>
    <div class="lateralInfo">
      <div class="menu"></div>
      <div class="data">
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--/div REMOVED -->
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

(Note that you had an extra `</div>` at the end of your HTML)

⋅⋅⋅

2. Use of CSS absolute or fixed positioning

If you want to avoid the use of JavaScript, you may want to use absolute or fixed positioning in your CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(128, 126, 126);
}

.something {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 10px;
}

.lateralInfo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.data {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.server {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header></header>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="something"></div>
    <div class="lateralInfo">
      <div class="menu"></div>
      <div class="data">
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
        <div class="server"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

---

Hope it helps